# Convert from long to wide format with multiple unique variables to other unique variables in R

Tags: r, casting, type-conversion, reshape2

I am trying to convert from long to wide format but multiple columns denote the unique rows. 
In the example below, the `block, density, species` columns denote the unique individuals. Every individual has 2 or 3 rows associated with area and size. I want to convert the area and size to wide format.

This is my dataset

```
block <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
species <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
den <- c("20","20","50","50","20","20","50","50","20","20","50","50","20","20","50","50","50")


block <- as.factor(block)
den <- as.factor(den)
species <- as.factor(species)

area <- c(1:17)
size <- c(17:33)

df <- data.frame(block, species, den, area, size)
```

I want to final dataset with only the unique individuals

```
  block   species   den   area.1  area.2  area.3  size.1  size.2  size.3
    1        A       20     1       2       NA      17      18      NA
    1        A       50     3       4       NA      19      20      NA
    .....
    2        B       50     15      16      17      31      32      33
```

Note: Other answers that I have persued do not use multiple columns to denote the uniquness of the rows

Comment: Using `data.table` : `library(data.table); setDT(df); dcast(df, block + species + den ~ rowid(block, species, den), value.var = c("area", "size"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column by group

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(block, species, den) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(area, size), names_sep = ".")
# A tibble: 8 x 9
#  block species den   area.1 area.2 area.3 size.1 size.2 size.3
#  <fct> <fct>   <fct>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 1     A       20         1      2     NA     17     18     NA
#2 1     A       50         3      4     NA     19     20     NA
#3 1     B       20         5      6     NA     21     22     NA
#4 1     B       50         7      8     NA     23     24     NA
#5 2     A       20         9     10     NA     25     26     NA
#6 2     A       50        11     12     NA     27     28     NA
#7 2     B       20        13     14     NA     29     30     NA
#8 2     B       50        15     16     17     31     32     33
```